# How to delete cart lists Item in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to delete the cart lists. I know it can delete in `document.queryselector` but I want to know if there have any good way to delete cart list and also price should change after delete together

https://codesandbox.io/s/shopping-cart-ycljl?file=/src/App.js
[image]

Comment: First off, direct DOM manipulation is a huge anti-pattern in react.  You should map your `cartLists` data to JSX instead of stringifying and setting innerHTML. Secondly, everything stored in an `x` variable, i.e. price and delete button, needs to be rendered as JSX into the UI in order to let react be able to handle deleting it.

Comment: Thanks, @Drew Can you edit codesandbox little bit to get an idea. I am very new to React so I am blank now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:** How to delete item in array?

In react you generally map an array to renderable JSX using array::map, which conveniently provides an index to use. You can pass this index to a callback and filter the array by indices ***not*** equal to the passed index.

```
removeByIndex = index => data.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
```

Here `i` is also the index passed in the array::filter function, and you can give the first argument (the current element) really *any* name, but since it doesn't matter a common convention is to name it "_" as in, fill in the blank, it doesn't matter.

**Code refactor:**

- Make App hold single source of truth, import data and pass to `Filter`
- Update `addToCart` callback to take `item` object and push into cart array
- Create `removeFromCart` callback to filter cart item by index
- Only store cart array and price (since used in a couple places) in state
- Use effect to reduce cart array to total price
- Use cart array length for number of items in cart
- Use cart array to map items versus DOM manipulation
- Don't use array index as react key
- Fix various syntax errors ("class" vs "className", etc..)

App

```
export default function App() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [cartLists, setCartLists] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPrice(cartLists.reduce((total, { price }) => total + price, 0));
  }, [cartLists]);

  const addToCart = item => setCartLists([...cartLists, item]);

  const removeFromCart = index =>
    setCartLists(cartList => cartList.filter((_, i) => i !== index));

  const clearCart = () => setCartLists([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

      <div className="my-2 bg-secondary p-3 text-white d-inline-block">
        <div className="font-weight-bold">
          <span className="totalitems">{cartLists.length}</span> - $
          <span className="totalprice">{price}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="row no-gutters">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            {/* cart item lists */}
            <div className="w-50 text-left">
              <h3>Cart Lists</h3>
              {cartLists.map(({ image, price, text }, index) => (
                <div
                  key={`${text}-${index}`}
                  className="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3"
                >
                  <img alt={image} src={image} className="w-25" />
                  <div className="d-flex mt-2 flex-column">
                    <h3>{text}</h3>
                    <h3 className="ml-auto price">${price}</h3>
                  </div>
                  <Delete onClick={() => removeFromCart(index)}>Delete</Delete>
                </div>
              ))}

              <h3>
                Total $<span className="totalprice2">{price}</span>
              </h3>
              <div className="d-flex my-3">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-secondary clearCart"
                  onClick={clearCart}
                >
                  Clear Cart
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary ml-2">CheckOut</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* filter section */}
            <div className="row mt-3">
              <Filter data={data} countBtn={addToCart} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Shopping Cart]